# Area Between two Planes

Tags: geometry

As a pool contractor I am searching for a better way to calculate required excavation and fill. Both pool floor and existing grades are represented by a simple slope, but they are not aligned. By this I mean the pool floor might slope at a right angle compared to the existing grades slope.

I want to treat both the pool floor and existing grade as a two planes.

Let pool depth be 3' to 5' and 20'length x 10'width...
  Problem A: Existing grade slopes from 4' to 6' over the same distance same direction.
  Problem B: Existing grade slopes from 2' to 4' over the same distance same direction.
  Problem C: Same as problem A but the existing grade slopes at a different angle (or direction)

I am looking for formulas that will provide me the amount of earth to excavate and fill required.

Comment: I’m guessing that the pool has the same cross-section when viewed from the side. In math talk, it’s a prism. So if you have an accurate representation of the cross-section, you find the area of that and multiply by the width of the pool, to get the volume. Does this help?